# Maven plugin: common dependency in plugin and project, create dependency class object in plugin from class in project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, classloader, maven-plugin

Good day,

I have the following setup:

- a maven dependency `dep1`, it contains an abstract class `A`
- another maven dependency `dep2`, which uses `dep1` as dependency, and has a class `Dep2Class` with constructor `Dep2Class(A a)`
- maven plugin `mvn-plugin`that uses `dep2` as dependency
- project `proj` that has `dep1` as dependency, uses `mvn-plugin` as plugin and defines a class `B extends A`

My objective at this point is that `mvn-plugin` loads class `B` from `proj` and feeds it to `Dep2Class`.

As you might already expect I am getting ClassCastException because `proj` is loaded with a different class loader than `mvn-plugin`. I have tried with URIClassLoader and Guava and got the same issue. Reflections appear to be working but the code becomes a mess because I have several Methods from `A` to call in `mvn-plugin`. I wanted to try ClassGraph but as far as I understood it does not work easily with GraalVM and I need to use GraalVM.

It sounds strange to me that few people encountered this issue, so I wanted to ask whether anyone has some explanations they can provide. Is there any change I should do in the design? or is there any way to solve the class loader problem?

Thanks a lot, cheers.